# Query to get primary key of table in access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-2.0

What query we need to write for access database to get primary key column name of a particular table.

I ma using c# and access database whose file format is .mdb. I am using OleDbConnection class.

I want to get primary key column name in access database using query which is something like select columnName from sys.information_schema. This query work with sql server. I want query something like this which work with ms access.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there is any query for access database to check perticular table have primary key or not and if that have primary key then return column name which contains primary key. I want to do this by using query .

Answer (score 2):

this could be of help: http://gsraj.tripod.com/dotnet/ado_net/ado.net_retrieving_database_metadata.html

together with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey.aspx

edit after comments:
i was wrong:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.* FROM MSysObjects
```

you'll have to google the details tho, gotta go...

Comment: I want query which give primary key column name associated with table. Above link done it by using OleDbConnection class but not query. I had already done it with OleDbConnection class but I want to done it using query.

Comment: if am not mistaken, the msjet engine does not carry metadata tables around... you'll have to use ado.net, but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: I know this is quite awhile later and that you wanted a query, but I have some additional information: 1) I don't think you can find the primary keys through a query using OLE Provider. 2) You can definitely get the primary keys via GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null). At least it worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable cols = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Constraint_Column_Usage,...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.constraint_column_usage%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. Just like what Awadhendra said i have to make an primary column that is hidden which is what i did.

this is the code that got the first column which is hidden.

```
String SelectedID = dgvInventory.Rows[dgvInventory.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```